# Selecting all if value is zero else select with condition mysql stored procdure

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like below

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `sp_srch_all`( IN `content_per_page` int,
                         IN `start` int,
                         IN `ag1`int,
                         IN `ag2` int,
                         IN `ht1` int,
                         IN `ht2` int,
                         IN `ms` varchar(20),
                         IN `rel` int,
                         IN `edu` varchar(30),
                         IN `gen` varchar(30),
                         IN `cas` varchar(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    SET @err = edu;
    ROLLBACK;
END;
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* 
FROM tbl_regisatration a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_caste b on b.cst_id = a.caste
LEFT JOIN tbl_religion c on c.rel_id = a.religion
LEFT JOIN tbl_height d on d.he_id = a.height
LEFT JOIN tbl_profiles_for e on e.prof_id = a.profile_for
where a.prof_status=0 
  and a.gender=gen 
  and a.religion=rel 
  and DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, a.dob) >= (ag1 * 365.25) 
  AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, a.dob) <= (ag2 * 365.25) 
  and ((a.height >= ht1) 
  AND (a.height <= ht2)) 
  and a.marital_status=ms 
  and FIND_IN_SET(a.education,@err) 
  and FIND_IN_SET(a.caste,cas)
order by a.prof_cat desc LIMIT content_per_page OFFSET start;
END
```

I want to ignore conditions like  `a.religion=rel ,FIND_IN_SET(a.education,@err)..` if its corresponding values are null else if not null check these conditions

Comment: Like ```.. and (FIND_IN_SET(a.education,@err) OR a.education IS NULL) ..```

Comment: PS. Your `ROLLBACK` statement in the handler is strange - there is no transaction or even any statement which can be rolled back in the handler scope.